# Currency Exchange Rate in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, currency-exchange-rates

From Mexico's official currency exchange website, http://dof.gob.mx/index.php, I need to pull the USD rate on the far right of the page into a simple math equation in a SQL Server 2005 query to calculate USD to Mexican Pesos for invoices.  Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: You mean screen scrape the rate? You don't and can't from SQL.

Comment: You could get the exchange rate XML from an application and send the XML to a SQL Server Stored Procedure. You can get the XML from a place like http://themoneyconverter.com/USD/rss.xml

Comment: Actually, get it from here on that site: http://www.dof.gob.mx/indicadores.xml

Comment: Dan, that may be the closest thing to what I need.  So,
1. Is there a way to get SQL to grab that XML file, say in a trigger
2. How do I drop that into a math calculation in a query, or
3. Should I use that to populate another table and then do the math?

Comment: SQL cannot scrape anything on it's own. It'll only take what's passed to it so you'll need a webservice or webpage to do the scraping and call a SQL proc to save the exchange rate.

Comment: I've never tried this, so I have no idea if it will work, but you could try grabbing the value from the web service from within a SQLCLR assembly.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler to pull date from this kind of web API service where you can simply calculate up-to-date conversion of **USD** to **MXN**:

http://openexchangerates.org/documentation

And then just store all prices either in **USD** or **MXN** in the database, and apply conversion when needed.

E.g. in this list of exchange rates all ratios are compared to **USD**. So **USD** to **MXN** ratio is now  **13.3744**. So to convert dollars to Peso you need to multiply amount in dollars to the exchange rate:

```
var dollars = 25;
var peso = dollars * 13.3744;
```

and `peso` value is:

```
334.36
```

I hope that'll help anyone!